# Changing action bar title dynamically not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-actionbar

I want to change the text of the action bar in a fragment dynamically when that fragment is created,but `activity?.actionBar?.title = movie.title` is not working.

I tried this too

```
activity?.actionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true)
activity?.actionBar?.title = movie.title
```

Comment: Use `supportActionBar?.title` instead

Comment: Also meke sure action bar and movie exists when you call this line

Comment: Im inside a fragment,i can't acces the action bar like that,that's why im using `activity.actionbar`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `actionBar` is deprecated and replaced with `supportActionBar`.
- Using `activity` within a fragment returns `FragmentActivity` which doesn't directly reference `supportActionBar` object; instead you need to cast that to `AppCompatActivity`) or to your custom name of the activity that hosts this fragment.

To fix this:

```
(requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true)
(requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = ...
```

Comment: Thanks,it worked,accepted your response,but can you tell me,what exactly is the FragmentActivity and why doesn't it refrence the action bar?

Comment: @DragosCiupe The `FragmentActivity` is the direct parent class of the  `AppCompatActivity`; but as activity classes evolve; they subclassed this `FragmentActivity` with that `AppCompatActivity` as of the support libraries; and therefore changed some stuff including the `actionBar` to `supportActionBar`; therefore; the `supportActionBar` only exists in the `AppCompatActivity`.. Of course the support libraries also deprecated now; and replaced with androidx; but in androidx they didn't change the name of the classes; but they created something like a parallel API packages with the same classes

Comment: Ok,it's a pretty good explanation,thanks.I have a new question though,do you think you can take a look please?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70028020/how-to-display-an-icon-when-swiping-items-in-recyclerview-with-item-touch-helper

Comment: Sure let me check it